# Javascript replace underscore + letter

Tags: javascript, replace

I would like to replace "_e" in my string "add_e"

```
var myString = "add_e";
myString = myString.replace(/?????/, '' );
```

Anyone have an idea plz ?

Thanks

Comment: `.replace('_e', '');`

Comment: myString.replace('_e', '')

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var myString = "add_e";
myString = myString.replace('_e', '');
```